# How to compare two hash table values in C#

Tags: c#, hashtable

I need to compare 2 hash table values. I can compare key and value using Containskey and ConatinsValue methods respectively. Is it possible to compare both key and value in single statement. need to check whether given key value pair is exist in hash table in efficient way. Can anyone suggest solution for this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean the same value inside two different hash tables, or two different values within the same hash table, but stored with different keys? Usually there is no need to check both key and value: have you evaluated a sort of reverse hashtable where key and value are exchanged? Have you tried other classes, like hashset or dictionary ?

Answer (score 2):

No. Because you first need to determine if the same key is in both lists. Then if it is in both you want to compare the actual values. This involves a two step process. Even if you found a single method to use, under the covers it would be doing the two step process. From your question I think you mean that you have two separate hash table instances.

On the other hand, if you can guarantee that each possible value generates a unique hash then the mere existence of the hash in the table implies its value is the same as the one you want to compare against. Then you only need to determine if the key is in the table and the extra step of comparing values is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear what you're asking. Do you want to check to see if the some key-value pair is in *both* `Hashtable` objects? Or do you have a pair from one `Hashtable` object that you want to check for its presence in the other?

The first is not possible to do in a single statement, unless you write your own helper method for the purpose. That said, doing so is a good idea, and that helper method should be written correctly, i.e. accessing the data efficiently.

The first step in implementing this correctly is to fix your code so that it's using `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` instead of `Hashtable`. Without actual code, it's impossible to know what types you'd use for `TKey` and `TValue`, so here's an example of the helper method that will work for any types:

```
static bool KeyValuePairExistsInBoth<TKey, TValue>(Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dict1, Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dict2, TKey key, TValue value)
{
    TValue value1, value2;

    if (!dict1.TryGetValue(key, out value1) || !dict2.TryGetValue(key, out value2))
    {
        return false;
    }

    return value.Equals(value1) && value.Equals(value2);
}
```

The important aspect here is the use of the `TryGetValue()` method, which allows you to check for the presence of the key and retrieve that key's value all in a single call.

If all you need to do is check in the second collection for the presence of the key-value pair you've retrieved from the first collection, then you can just use the `TryGetValue()` method directly on the second collection, and then compare the value returned against the value from the first collection. Very similar to the above, but of course you don't need to check the first collection for the presence of the pair, since that's where you got it in the first place.

Comment: Shorter but less readable is something like this: return dict1.TryGetValue(key, out value1) && dict2.TryGetValue(key, out value2)) && value.Equals(value1) && value.Equals(value2);

Answer (score -1):

This should do it:

```
hash1[key] == hash2[key]
```

It's true if the key is either in both with the same value, or of it's missing in both.

Comment: don't we need to care for exception if key is present in the collection?